# Get newly created Item ID after Copy Item Nintex

Tags: workflow

i have created a Nintex Workflow in Sp10 which after a few checks, duplicates the current item via COPY ITEM to the same list.
What i now need is to change 2 values of that newly created item(status and Ready) but i am unable to get the new id of the just created item.

there are too much columns to use the Create Item action nor is it the customers wish to copy the item to a hidden list and that another workflow edits the values before copying the Item to the original list.

is there any way to get the id for the duplicated item? I am not so familiar with Webservice.

regards
Pascal

Answer (score 1):

I came across such scenario. As "COPY ITEM" workflow action do not return newly created Item "ID", I used below steps to resolve the problem:

1. Store the Values of "Current Item" in Workflow variables as required. (In your case status and Ready).

   e.g. `OldStatus = Status` `OldReady = Ready`
2. Use "Update Item" workflow action and update the "Current Item" with your desired values required for newly created Item (In your case status and Ready).
3. Use "Copy Item" workflow action and copy the "Current Item" to desired Library/List.
   At this step your newly created Item will have your desired values.
4. Here we basically revert the "OLD" values of current item. So, Use "Update Item" workflow action and update the "Current Item" with its original values.

   i.e.  `Status = OldStatus`
         `Ready = OldReady`

I know this is not the best solution but it will work.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in 3 blocks:

1. Copied Item
2. Queried the items with a common denominator (in my case it was the same person's item that was being copied)
   -Sort the query 3,2,1 by ID number
   -Store the ID number in a variable (not collection, you only need the first one)
3. Updated parts of the item by referencing the ID number